# Sum of rows by year with total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum rows by year plus get total at last column as shown in table and if possible also show total at the end row. I tried my best but could not get the desired result. This is what I am trying.

```
SELECT city
    ,[date]
    ,sum(price) AS Total
FROM [payer]
GROUP BY city
    ,[date]

+----------+------+------+-------+
|   City   | 2018 | 2019 | Total |
+----------+------+------+-------+
| New York |    4 |    6 |    10 |
| Toronto  |    8 |   12 |    20 |
| Total    |   12 |   18 |       |
+----------+------+------+-------+
```

**You may create table with data from below code.**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payer](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [price] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into payer values(1,'newyork','2018',2)
insert into payer values(2,'newyork','2018',2)
insert into payer values(3,'newyork','2019',3)
insert into payer values(4,'newyork','2019',3)
insert into payer values(5,'toronto','2018',4)
insert into payer values(6,'toronto','2018',4)
insert into payer values(7,'toronto','2019',6)
insert into payer values(8,'toronto','2019',6)
```

Comment: i am trying but getting some errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grouping sets` and conditional aggregation:

```
select coalesce(city, 'Total'),
       sum(case when [date] = '2018' then price end) as sum_2018,
       sum(case when [date] = '2019' then price end) as sum_2019,
       sum(price) as total
from [payer] p
where [date] in ('2018', '2019')
group by grouping sets ( (city), () );
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=43ff081d002de21640250ac7c14d58df) is a db<>fiddle.

First, calling a column `date` is a bad idea, because that is the name of a data type.  It is allowed, but I would recommend a better name.

Second, DATEs should be stored as `date` -- NOT as a string.  It is a really bad practice to store columns with the wrong data type.

In this case, what you call a `date` is quite misleading, because it is only the year.  I would recommend calling the column something like `year` and defining the type to be an integer.

Comment: @NaveedUllah . . . I fixed the answer and made some comments about the naming conventions in the table.

Comment: I can understand your points, basically i was just trying to keep things simple in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this using `PIVOT` as shown below.

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT City
        ,[2018]
        ,[2019]
    FROM (
        SELECT city
            ,DATE
            ,total
        FROM (
            SELECT City
                ,DATE
                ,Sum(price) AS Total
            FROM payer
            GROUP BY city
                ,DATE
            ) a
        ) d
    pivot(max(total) FOR DATE IN (
                [2018]
                ,[2019]
                )) piv
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte

UNION

SELECT 'total' AS city
    ,sum([2018]) AS [2018]
    ,sum([2019]) AS [2019]
FROM cte
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/EDZMA79417).
To get the vertical total you need to write your query as shown below.

```
SELECT City
    ,[2018]
    ,[2019]
    ,[2018] + [2019] AS [Total]
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM cte

    UNION

    SELECT 'total' AS city
        ,sum([2018]) AS [2018]
        ,sum([2019]) AS [2019]
    FROM cte
    ) final
```

Here is the [**demo**](https://rextester.com/OXEV73917) given.

Comment: best answer so far, just missing total at the last column and last row.

Comment: @NaveedUllah I have updated the answer please check. You can check the demo on link https://rextester.com/QFXV74198

Comment: your answer was also good enough but sorry i have to select one as correct answer.

Comment: @NaveedUllah it is enough to let me know you could upvote.